# Retrieving the last two days record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how to get last two days record here is my query but getting errors.

```
function getbdologHistoryByRefManuals($obj)
{
    $this->db->select('bdo_logs.*,transaction_statuses.status');
    $this->db->from('bdo_logs');
    $this->db->join('transactions','transactions.id=bdo_logs.id');
    $this->db->join('transaction_statuses','transaction_statuses.id=transactions.trans_status_id');
    $this->db->where('log_date >', ADDDATE( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -2 DAY ));

    $query = $this->db->get();

    //echo $this->db->last_query();
    if($query->num_rows() == 0){
        return null;
    }

            return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `last two days records`?

Comment: it means i want two days record mean today and yesterday record

Comment: what is your log_date field type. date or datetime?

Comment: Downvoted, for not stating the error in the question. In general, a question that asks how to do a database query ought to provide a schema too - don't make people guess your database structure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getbdologHistoryByRefManuals($obj)
{
    $this->db->select('bdo_logs.*,transaction_statuses.status');
    $this->db->from('bdo_logs');
    $this->db->join('transactions','transactions.id=bdo_logs.id');
    $this->db->join('transaction_statuses','transaction_statuses.id=transactions.trans_status_id');
    $this->db->where('DATE(log_date) >', 'ADDDATE( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -2 DAY )');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 0){
        return null;
    }

    return $query->result();
}
```

You are missing to wrap ADDDATE function in where clause

EDIT:
Or alternatively you can call it like this

```
$query  ="  SELECT
                bdo_logs.*,
                transaction_statuses.status
            FROM bdo_logs
            JOIN transactions 
                ON transactions.id  =   bdo_logs.id
            JOIN transaction_statuses 
                ON transaction_statuses.id  =   transactions.trans_status_id
            WHERE DATE(log_date) > ADDDATE( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -2 DAY )";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: i want latest two days record not last two record.

Comment: @Micheal: no need to shout, Raheel is trying to help you. Bear in mind that when you receive an answer here, you may need to tweak it for your use case. +1

Comment: I agree with halfer. And also, if you dont say WHY it doesn't work, there is no chance that someone fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 days"));
echo $today;
echo '<br />';
echo $newdate;
```

Now, Put `$newdate` in the where condition.